# How to get Last WeekNumber when week is first week of the year in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, dateadd, getdate, datepart

I am trying to get last weeknumber when week is first week of the year (e.g. current date is 1/1/2017)
Below query works for all other week except the first week of the year.
However below query returns nothing for the first week of the year.

```
 where DateDim_Date.YEAR=year(DATEADD(Day, -7, getDate()))
 and DateDim_Date.WEEKNUMBER = datePart(wk,getDate())-1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
where DateDim_Date.YEAR=year(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getDate()))
 and DateDim_Date.WEEKNUMBER = datePart(wk,DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()))
```

You want to get (weeknumber of (current date - 7 days)), not (weeknumber of current date) -1